# Add stroke to SVG Image element

Tags: css, svg, polygon, polyline

Is it possible for me to add a stroke to the svg image element in this code snippet?

```html
<div style="width:100%; height:100%;">
<svg style="width:100%; height:100%;">
          <g>
                <clipPath id="myclippath" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
                      <polygon points="0 0, 0.4 0, 0.5 0.5, 0.6 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1" />
                </clipPath>
        </g>
        <image x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" clip-path="url(#myclippath)"
               xlink:href="https://a248.e.akamai.net/assets.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/Octocat.png" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

[image: Like this]
 *<-I would like a stroke around the clipped edges like this.*